# Reducing $ab' + cb + ac$ to $ab' + cb$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Boolean expressions $I = ab' + cb + ac$ and $J = ab' + cb$ have the same truth table. Then why expression $I$ can't be reduced to expression $J$?

Comment: @ Henning Makholm, My textbook says, in a true/false question that "I" can't be reduced to "J".

Comment: Sometimes textbooks contain errors.

Comment: @ozo, I agree. I think it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think $I$ *can't* be rewritten to $J$? Here's one way to do it algebraically:

$$\begin{align} I &= ab'+cb+ac
\\&= ab'+cb+ac(b+b')
\\&= ab'+cb+acb+acb'
\\&= ab'+acb'+cb+acb
\\&= (a+ac)b'+(c+ac)b
\\&= ab' + cb &= J
\end{align}$$

Comment: I see now both are equal, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the value of $b$, $J$ is either $a$ or $c$. But $a$ and $c$ must be *true* if $ac$ is true. Therefore, $ac$ does not add anything to expression $I$.

A more detailed explanation and historic background can be found in this article on the [Consensus Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem). Also have a look at a [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873354/what-is-the-lor-symbol/873414#873414).